# Flutter forEach typing: Unable to type a forach callback (The argument type N can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)')

Tags: flutter, dart, foreach, typing

total noob question here:

[image: dart forEach typing problem]

If **I don't specify a type**, it says `Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file.dart(implicit_dynamic_parameter)`

When **I add the type `double`** in front of the function param, it says `The argument type 'void Function(double)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'`

Also I really don't understand **why the type is not inferred from the array declaration** above ?

```dart
final List strengths = <double>[.05]; // type of array items in a forEach loop seems obvious
```

I have tried a lot of different things and syntax that I saw everywhere on the internet but the only way to fix my problem was to delete `analysis_options.yaml`

I am sure I really miss the obvious...**Could you point me the right direction ?**

---

Other related questions I have saw and couldn't adapt to my case:

- [Flutter DART "Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077886/flutter-dart-try-adding-an-explicit-type-like-dynamic-or-enable-implicit-dyn)
- [The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?' after null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484113/the-argument-type-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-void-funct)
- [Flutter - Argument of type function can't be assigned to the parameter of type `void function()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762455/flutter-argument-of-type-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-of-type)

The real function code:

```dart
MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
  final List strengths = <double>[.05];
  final swatch = <int, Color>{};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  strengths.forEach((double strength) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  });
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was reopened.  This is a duplicate of [Why is dart wrongly inferring my generic parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61805709/) which explains why `strengths` ends up with a type `List<dynamic>` instead of `List<double>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare Your List like this:

```
final List<double> strengths = <double>[.05];
```

Comment: Hi perfect answer! Could you give more details on why this is needed please ?

Comment: Hi..!! You have to declare list with data type to perform operations in a better way.. it will provide suggestions according to your data type

Comment: @GLAND_PROPRE See the linked duplicate for why this is needed.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `List` keyword from the first line

before

```
final List strengths = <double>[.05];
```

after

```
final strengths = <double>[.05];
```

Comment: Hi works nicely but could you explain further please ?

Comment: you are declaring a final variable and you gave it the value in the same same line to declare it so the value will never changes and its already have a value of [.05]
dart is smart enough to know the strengths is List of double case you give it value with that data type